# Is it possible to access external XMLHttpRequests within a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Essentially, I'm creating a Chrome extension that needs to read a request being sent by the website to one of their internal servers and returns a JSON object which I would like my extension to be able to read.

I've wanted to use something I've found (probably here, I've done so much research I kinda forget). This would allow me to see any XMLHttpRequest.open calls, however it appears within the extension it's using a local XMLHttpRequest.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

var myOpen = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    this.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4)
            alert(this.responseText);
    }
    //call original
    this.realOpen (method, url, async, user, password);
}

//ensure all XMLHttpRequests use our custom open method
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = myOpen;
```

What I want is to use this xhr to trigger my extension into action, anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) for informations about Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequests and an example. You need to allow your extension to request from an specific domain (or "http://*/").

Comment: I've already done this, and allowed "https://*/", "http://*/", in the mainfest file, the extension still continues to use a local version. The changes I make only seem to impact either the background page, or... nothing. As if I do this in the extension script itself, the changes never stick.